# How to create a jar using maven written in scala that can be added and used in other project

Tags: scala, maven, jar

I am trying to create a simple calculator program in scala and want to create a jar from it.
That jar I want to use in other project i.e. methods of that class

Below is the code.

```
package com.umarchine.JarCheck

class CustomCalculator {

  def customAdd(a: Int, b:Int): Int ={
    a+b
  }

  def customSub(a: Int, b:Int): Int ={
    a-b
  }

  def customMul(a: Int, b:Int): Int ={
    a*b
  }

  def customDiv(a: Int, b:Int): Int ={
    a/b
  }

}
```

Now, I have used maven clean install to create a jar. Pom.xml used for this code is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.umarchine.JarCheck</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.11.5</scala.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>


</project>
```

In the other project I have added the dependency as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.umarchine.JarCheck</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

By this dependency, jar is imported in the other project.
However, I am not able to import the class or use its method in the other project.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Try with `<artifactId>calculator_2.11</artifactId>` _(note the `_2.11`)_. Also, I would recommend you to use **SBT** instead of **Maven**.

Comment: Not working with this as well

Comment: Can you check your local repository to confirm the jar is there?

Comment: yes it is there.. added in other project as well

Comment: _"added in other project as well"_ what does that mean? That you are able to import it in other project? Can you share the full path here the JAR is as well as its full name?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to create a calculator in scala with methods as add, sub, mul and divide. Then I am trying to create a jar from it. This jar I am using in another project say project X which wants to use the method defined in calculator jar. I am able to import the jar in project X but not able to import the class calculator code of which I have posted above.

Comment: How are you sure the jar is imported if the classes are not? How did you try to import the classes? are you sure the library jar exists? Can you give us the path where that jar got installed

Comment: When I ran maven clean and install jar is deployed at local maven directory. Post that I have added dependency in project x pom.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210507/discussion-between-umar-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).

Answer (score 0):

The code that I have written for calculator was correct.

Only thing I was missing was a dependency in pom.xml.

I have added below maven plugins in pom.xml and post that the jar that was created worked fine in other project.

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```